# Plesk can't/won't/doesn't-know-how-to reload php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, php5, php.ini

So Plesk is pretty much my daily nightmare but I'm stuck with it.  Today's practical joke on me is that it won't seem to load changes I make to the `php.ini`.  I'm trying to get a file's contents (via the appropriately named `file_get_contents()`) and am coming up against the `open_basedir` restrictions - a line which I have removed from **ALL** `.ini` files listed in `phpinfo()`.  There is now NO reference whatsoever to `open_basedir` in any of the loaded `.ini`'s.  I've restarted Apache more times than I care to think of.

The script loads the contents of two extensionless log files and displays them in a browser.  Oddly, it loads one of the scripts just fine even though it also is not permitted by the `open_basedir` config item.

The error continues and `phpinfo()` still shows it as being a configured path.

Does anyone have any idea what may be the cause of this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've just `grep`'d my entire server storage, there are officially no `open_basedir` lines in any `*.ini` files (not even commented) which is making me think that this configuration is cached somewhere that persists after reloading Apache?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that you run your sites in FastCGI and not mod_php? Because when mod_php is effective, open_basedir can easily be in Apache files and not in .ini.

Rather than grep all .ini files on a server, I would suggest to click site name in Plesk and

1. check which mode is used (mod_php or FastCGI)
2. go to "PHP Settings" tab and tune open_basedir to whatever value you want. Plesk will modify required files appropriately for both mod_php and FastCGI modes

Comment: Thank you sir.  I had to disable FastCGI owing to .htaccess issues ages ago and I will admit that I did not know this made php.ini redundant.  Solved my problem perfectly.